# PHP serialize for many inputs

Tags: php, serialization

I have this HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="data_first" value="9" />
   <input type="hidden" name="data_second" value="2" />
   <input type="hidden" name="date" value="2018-01-25" />
   <input type="text" name="posted_data" value="0.1" />
</form>
```

I want combine this Posted data, with `serialize function`.

I can serialize only one input. 
example: `serialize($_POST['posted_data']);`
I need function like this:

`serialize($_POST['posted_data'],$_POST['data_first'],$_POST['data_second'],$_POST['date']);`

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `serialize($_POST);`?

Comment: `serialize($_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do -

```
serialize($_POST);
```

It will serialize all the posted data. And then process them accordingly.

**Update**

You can use input arrays -

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="data[data_first]" value="9" />
   <input type="hidden" name="data[data_second]" value="2" />
   <input type="hidden" name="data[date]" value="2018-01-25" />
   <input type="text" name="data[posted_data]" value="0.1" />
</form>
```

And

```
serialize($_POST['data']);
```

Will serialize those specific inputs present in `data`.

Comment: I have many inputs, I need to serialize only this inputs  $_POST['posted_data'],$_POST['data_first'],$_POST['data_second'],$_POST['date']

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways  
1) By sending post array
 
  e.g  `serialize($_POST)`

2) By sending post data through array
   e.g `serialize(array($_POST['posted_data'],$_POST['data_first'],$_POST['data_second'],$_POST['date']));`